# jquery datatable serverside issue on webserver(ASP.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

Every thing is perfect on local server but when i host on my server than it throw error:
DataTables warning: table id=tblMember - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7 
Call Ajax using Jquery and Ajax pass on Web service.

Code:

```
table = $('#tblMember').DataTable({
    'bProcessing': true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sServerMethod": 'POST',
    "sAjaxSource": URL,
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "YearId", "value": YearId });
    },
    columns: [
                  { 'data': 'UId' },
                  { 'data': 'MemberId' },
                  { 'data': 'MemName' },
                  { 'data': 'Address' },
                  { 'data': 'Sector' },
                  { 'data': 'Division' },
                  { 'data': 'Village' },
                  { 'data': 'ContactNo1' },
                  { 'data': 'TotalMember' },
                  {
                      data: null,
                      className: "center",
                      defaultContent: '<a id="btnEdit" href="#">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="btnDelete">Delete</a>'
                  }
    ],
});
}
```

Comment: And the question is.... ????

Comment: pls read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you actually read what the technical note said at http://datatables.net/tn/7 ?